# Change Component Properties In GridView from a javascript function

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to create a GUI with Qt quick and I will have a lot of data in multiple files and I will constantly update the GUI through C++ (leave logic there) that will emit to a certain JS function(not sure if this is the correct way to do things).

I made a simple example with `Grid`(Not `GridView`) layout because i found how to change the first rectangle's color but not the nested one. Here it is:

```
Column{
    spacing:2

    Grid{
        id:grid
        columns: 2
        rows:2
        spacing: 10
        Repeater{
            model:4

            Rectangle{
                id:rect1
                width:100
                height:100
                color:"red"
                Rectangle{
                    id:rect2
                    width:25
                    height: 25
                    color:"black"
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: rect1.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenter: rect1.verticalCenter
                }

            }
        }
    }

    Button{
        text:"Click me"
        width:50
        height:50
        onClicked: {
            for (var i = 0; i <grid.children.length; ++i)
                column.children[i].color="green";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a JavaScript function for any of that? The delegate in the GridView can just react to changes of its model entry's data

Comment: I am a beginner and i am trying to find how to create my Interface i am not sure if this is the correct way. I edited my question just now but i as i read in documentation you need to separate logic from  graphics so i thought that my c++ function will signal my javascript function and javascript function will change the colors..

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem after a simple try of accessing second `Rectangle` the same way that I access the `Rectangle` children of `Grid`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < column.children.length; ++i)
    grid.children[i].children[0].color="green";
```